# how can i regexp this?

Tags: regex, preg-replace

With what regexp can i process strings like

```
2.3.5...9 
4...
...
```

to

```
2.3.5.0.0.9
4.0.0.0
0.0.0.0
```

I've tried `preg_replace('/\.([^0-9])/', '.0', $mystring)` but no luck, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace('/^(?=\.)|(?<=\.)(?=\.|$)/', '0', $mystring)`

This covers the cases

- start of the string followed by dot
- two dots
- dot followed by the end of the string

Answer (score 1):

Your current approach is close, but to make it work we can try using lookarounds.  Replace:

```
(?<=^|\.)(?=\.|$)
```

with `0`.

```
$mystring = "2.3.5...9";
$output = preg_replace('/(?<=^|\.)(?=\.|$)/', '0', $mystring);
echo $output;
```

Here is a brief explanation of the regex logic:

```
(?<=^|\.)    position is preceded by either the start of the string, or another dot
(?=\.|$)     position is followed by either the end of the string, or another dot
```

Answer (score 0):

If input string is an IPv4 (like) string (with ot without digits) then do this:

```
echo preg_replace('~\B~', '0', '...'); // 0.0.0.0
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/9SzfpD/1)